When Installing wordpress through softaculous showing errors
In our domain we are not able to install wordpress plugin as it showing errors like
check_charset.php, wp-config.php, htaccess can anyone help us to how to solve this issue or any link to resolve this issue. please guide us

What specifically are the errors please? Are those files missing? I don't recognise check_charset. Is it trying and failing to write to those files? I haven't done a clean install in ages but I didn't think that was an error, just a prompt to make changes manually.

If these errors are specific to Softaculous then you'd probably need to ask them or your host directly for help.

I wonder if Softaculous's scripts just need updating for a newer version of WordPress?

This seems to be a problem with Softaculous, which would be off topic for this Stack. Try installing WP manually.
